# Interactive R session - Get window width for print truncation?

Tags: r

Is is possible to access the current window width (in terms of characters) in an interactive session?

Say that we have a long string

```
x <- paste0(c(rep(letters, 10)), collapse = "")
```

One can use `stringr` to truncate the string and view it. For example:

```
stringr::str_trunc(x, 50)
```

results in

```
[1] "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstu..."
```

Would it be possible to make the truncating width variable so that the printed string is as large as possible while fitting in a single line?

Comment: While it may not give you the actual width of the containing window, you can use `getOption("width")` to find out what the user or R terminal has defined as the width. In some cases (e.g., in the RStudio IDE) it is automatically updated without the need for user-intervention.

Comment: See [`?options`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/options.html) (or `?getOption`, different funcs, slightly different return value, identical effect) and scroll down to `'width'`.